# Limited connectivity?

Tags: opensuse, vpn

I have a strange issue with Network Manager in OpenSUSE 15 Leap / GNOME 3.26.

So everything works fine actually, but after a while I get this X mark on wired connection in NM applet, but the connections to internet (ethernet and VPN set through Network Manager) work just fine. When I restart the connection it's normal again, but X shows soon quite randomly.

I have set up the static IP address in Yast.

EDIT: I am on wired connection and this X happens when I am also on VPN.

The picture is shown below (red spot) but if you need more information just let me know.

What could that be? [image]

Comment: Let me guess, the X shows inside the VPN, and when you get out of the VPN it disappears. Is that so? However, it is not entirely clear why you are talking about setting up a static IP address in an wifi connection. Would you please edit your question explaining what is that static IP address about?

Comment: You are correct. I am on wired connection and this X happens when I am also on VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing might be (and is) expected behaviour, especially if it is a full tunnel VPN without full Internet access, and depending on configuration.

Whilst connection health indicator icons in the past, just relied upon physical test/presence of connection+having an IP address, nowadays they also do some DNS and even HTTP(S) connectivity tests to some URLs in most of the modern operating systems.

Your VPN service might have a slightly more restricted configuration or a DNS "firewall"/filter, and whilst that does not stop you from doing your normal work, somehow it is making the connectivity tests mark the tests as failed, and hence the "X".

If you are supposed to have full Internet access when the VPN is active, it might be worth opening a ticket with the VPN provider. ( I bet you are not the only user with this symptom. )

Comment: Thanks. If this is normal, then I am "relieved". However, I will check with VPN service.

Comment: This situation can happen also with some wireless or firewall, or more convuluted DNS configurations. It is a "known" issue. Hence my initial comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than guess you can look at NetworkManager's logs via `journalctl` and see why it's going into this error state:

```
$ journalctl -u NetworkManager
Jul 31 17:41:04 centos7 dhclient[794]: bound to 10.0.2.15 -- renewal in 42481 seconds.
Aug 01 05:29:05 centos7 dhclient[794]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 10.0.2.2 port 67 (xid=0x4c2d7b4e)
Aug 01 05:29:05 centos7 dhclient[794]: DHCPACK from 10.0.2.2 (xid=0x4c2d7b4e)
Aug 01 05:29:05 centos7 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1533115745.8815] dhcp4 (eth0):   address 10.0.2.15
Aug 01 05:29:05 centos7 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1533115745.8815] dhcp4 (eth0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Aug 01 05:29:05 centos7 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1533115745.8815] dhcp4 (eth0):   gateway 10.0.2.2
Aug 01 05:29:05 centos7 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1533115745.8816] dhcp4 (eth0):   lease time 86400
Aug 01 05:29:05 centos7 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1533115745.8816] dhcp4 (eth0):   nameserver '10.0.2.3'
Aug 01 05:29:05 centos7 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1533115745.8816] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed bound -> bound
Aug 01 05:29:05 centos7 dhclient[794]: bound to 10.0.2.15 -- renewal in 35729 seconds.
```

If you need additional logging details you can increase NetworkManager's loglevel:

*current level*

```
$ nmcli general logging
LEVEL  DOMAINS
INFO   PLATFORM,RFKILL,ETHER,WIFI,BT,MB,DHCP4,DHCP6,PPP,IP4,IP6,AUTOIP4,DNS,VPN,SHARING,SUPPLICANT,AGENTS,SETTINGS,SUSPEND,CORE,DEVICE,OLPC,INFINIBAND,FIREWALL,ADSL,BOND,VLAN,BRIDGE,TEAM,CONCHECK,DCB,DISPATCH,AUDIT,SYSTEMD,PROXY
```

The above shows that the loglevel is set to `INFO` and the DOMAINS is set to `PLATFORM....`. To increase the loglevel:

```
$ nmcli general logging level DEBUG
```

Seeing that it was increased:

```
$ journalctl -u NetworkManager | tail -1
Aug 01 06:32:26 centos7 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1533119546.8161] manager: logging: level 'DEBUG' domains 'PLATFORM,RFKILL,ETHER,WIFI,BT,MB,DHCP4,DHCP6,PPP,IP4,IP6,AUTOIP4,DNS,VPN,SHARING,SUPPLICANT,AGENTS,SETTINGS,SUSPEND,CORE,DEVICE,OLPC,INFINIBAND,FIREWALL,ADSL,BOND,VLAN,BRIDGE,TEAM,CONCHECK,DCB,DISPATCH,AUDIT,SYSTEMD,PROXY'
```

#### References

- [NetworkManager.conf](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html)
- [Where does NetworkManager store its logs?](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/40975/where-does-networkmanager-store-its-logs/)